# YUV frame averaging using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, yuv

I am trying to read a yuv video, then perform frame averaging, however, I run into problems when doing so, my code is shown below (this was made by combining a yuv reader and well as code to split the frame into the separate y, u,v components as well as adding what I thought was the way to proceed with this)
I get an error that the argument should be int or none not float but doesn't reference the line, but I do know this has to do with the reading the yuv file part. I am trying to average every two frames within the video. The YUV file is 10bit, 420

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
class readYUV:
    def __init__(self, filename, size):
        self.height, self.width = size
        self.frame_len = self.width * self.height * 3 / 2
        self.f = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.shape = (int(self.height*1.5), self.width)

    def read_raw(self):
        try:
            raw = self.f.read(self.frame_len)
            yuv = np.frombuffer(raw, dtype=np.uint8)
            yuv = yuv.reshape(self.shape)
        except Exception as e:
            print (str(e))
            return False, None
        return True, yuv

    def read(self):
        ret, yuv = self.read_raw()
        if not ret:
            return ret, yuv
        bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21)
        return ret, bgr

    def make_lut_u():
        return np.array([[[i, 255 - i, 0] for i in range(256)]], dtype=np.uint8)

    def make_lut_v():
        return np.array([[[0, 255 - i, i] for i in range(256)]], dtype=np.uint8)
            # otherwise, split the frame into its respective channels

    def splitter(img):
        cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        cv2.waitKey(30)
        img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
        y, u, v = cv2.split(img_yuv)

        lut_u, lut_v = make_lut_u(), make_lut_v()

        # Convert back to BGR so we can apply the LUT and stack the images
        y = cv2.cvtColor(y, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        u = cv2.cvtColor(u, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        v = cv2.cvtColor(v, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        u_mapped = cv2.LUT(u, lut_u)
        v_mapped = cv2.LUT(v, lut_v)

        result = np.vstack([img, y, u_mapped, v_mapped])
        return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "file.yuv"
    size = (3840, 2160)
    cap = readYUV(filename, size)
    while 1:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.waitKey(30)
        result1 = splitter(frame)
        ret2, frame2 = cap.read()
        cv2.waitKey(30)
        result2 = splitter(frame2)
        result = (result1 +result2)/2
        cv2.imwrite('average.png', result)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For reading from file properly, cast `frame_len` to `int`: `self.frame_len = int(self.width * self.height * 3 / 2)`

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I'm getting that 'splitter' is not defined though it has been, any ideas about that?

Comment: I tried to fix your code, but I can't understand what is the purpose of converting to RGB back and forth, and why do you need the LUTs. Another problem is that you are writing that your frames are 10bit, but the code reads them as 8bit (NV21 format is 8 bits per component). The parallel of NV12 format for 10bit is called [P010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/10-bit-and-16-bit-yuv-video-formats) (I don't know if there is a 10bit parallel format to NV21).

Comment: I've managed to sort out the averaging part, what would be an efficient method to read a 10bit 420 yuv as I understand the current method is inefficient ?

Comment: The main problem is that you are reading **8bit** yuv 420 instead of **10bit** yuv 420. The code assumes the format is NV21. Find out what is the true format.